# Drawing lines from point to polygon at angle to shortest line between same point and polygon?

Tags: arcpy, angles

I have a polygon with a point outside. I was able to calculate the shortest distance between the point and polygon and draw a line for the same. Now, I need to draw radiating lines from the point, on either side of the shortest line, such that they meet the polygon. The shortest line is the reference and the radial lines are decided by angle between them. The angles are  theta,2*theta,3*theta etc

---

I didn't come up with a code for whatever I have managed so far; rather, I used a bunch of functions using arcpy. I'm still in the initial process of understanding the possibilities and what part of my requirement needs custom coding.

The steps that I followed are as follows:

1. Used Near_analysis to find the nearest point on the polygon from my point. It added the location(X and Y) of the nearest point in the attribute table
2. Using the coordinates of the nearest point and the coordinates of my point, I implemented the XYtoLine_management to draw the line.

At this point I'm stuck. I've been trying bearing to distance but that uses geographic north as reference.

It not much of a code as it has several errors which are irrelevant, with a few results generated as per my needs.

I'm still exploring some options.

[image: Image describing the geometry]

Comment: Do you just have one point and one polygon?  How many times do you need to do this?  I am wondering if you need a script or if you don't have too many you can use the edit tools manually.

Comment: It sounds like you already have some code "to calculate the shortest distance between the point and polygon and draw a line for the same" so I think you should present that to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: You can use plugin "Azimuth and distance" and make lines to your object with azimuth. Then , cut overlapping lines with geoprocessing tool difference, and calculate lenght. I have screenshot but I cannot answer on your question, only comment. QGIS

Comment: @DMusketeer From one point ill generate those lines at incremental values of theta till some threshold criteria is reached. In this case I will effectively have a triangle with my point and the two points at intersection of the two lines on either side of the shortest distance, with none of the intermediate lines that are visible in the sketch

Then repeat this for hundreds of points all around the polygon leaving me with that many triangles with overlapping regions on the polygons
I hope that provides enough clarification

Comment: @PolyGeo I have edited the post to explain the process that I employed. You may also refer to my reply to the comment by DMusketeer. Please do let me know if this added information is sufficient. Your guidance is valued. Thankyou!

Comment: This is not yet where I could vote to re-open your question.  We are happy to help you with your code but not to write it for you.

Comment: Oh not at all. I don't expect the code to be written for me. I only expect some direction in this regard. I have started working with ArcGIS recently and there seem to be so many options and tools, most of which I only came across in such forums. Far too many to easily understand what specific process will suit my needs. I am still working on it and will definitely update the post with whatever code that I am finally able to put together. Thankyou!